# On a particular version of the spectral theorem for bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

[Dimock's](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-mechanics-and-quantum-field-theory/06B6B13B344880D492F4A09C9C1E713D) book states the spectral theorem for bounded operators as follows.

**Theore:** Let $T$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Then there exists a measure space $(\mathcal{M},\mu)$, a bounded measurable function $\tau: \mathcal{M}\to \mathbb{R}$ and a unitary operator $V:\mathcal{H}\to L^{2}(\mathcal{M},d\mu)$ such that $T = V^{-1}[\tau]V$ where $[\tau]$ is the operator multiplication by $\tau$.

The proof of the above result is omitted in Dimock's book but he refers to [Reed and Simon's](https://www.amazon.com.br/Functional-Analysis-Methods-Mathematical-Physics-ebook/dp/B00BCRMN4G) book for the proof. I've looked the latter, specifically in the section VII.2 - The spectral Theorem, but I did not find the exactly statement. There are some results such as Borel functional calculus and other spectral theorem results, but the one I think is the closest to Dimock's theorem is the following.

**Theorem:** Let $A$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator on a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Then there exists a finite measure space $(\mathcal{M},\mu)$, a bounded function $\tau$ on $\mathcal{M}$ and a unitary map $U: \mathcal{H}\to L^{2}(\mathcal{M},\mu)$ so that:
\begin{eqnarray}
(UAU^{-1}f)(m) = F(m)f(m) \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}

As you can see, this is not Dimock's version: in Reed & Simon's version, $\mathcal{H}$ is *separable* and $(\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is *finite*. Furthermore, it does not state explicitly that $A = U^{-1}[\tau]U$.

**Question:** Does Dimock's version follows from the above result from Reed & Simon (or maybe another result from this book)? And in the affirmative case, how to prove it?

Comment: Here's a link that may be helpful. http://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/files/2018/04/specthm.pdf

Comment: This was crossposted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370558/on-a-specific-version-of-the-spectral-theorem-for-bounded-operators

(this should not be re-deleted; posting links between cross-posted questions is best practice)

Comment: @MathMath I came here from there. Just wanted to reassure you that my comment is not an indictment. :)

Comment: @Neal oh, sure! I understand your point! No problem at all! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of books that have this theorem, but to answer your question, yes, you can derive the nonseparable result from the separable one. Pick a nonzero vector $v \in H$ and let $H_v$ be the closed span of $\{v, Av, A^2v, \ldots\}$. This subspace is invariant for $A$, and since $A$ is self-adjoint its orthocomplement $H_v^{\perp}$ is also invariant for $A$. So we can now pick a nonzero vector $v' \in H_v^{\perp}$ and let $H_{v'}$ be the closed span of $\{v', Av', A^2v', \ldots\}$, and so on. The result is that you can decompose $H$ into a direct sum of separable subspaces each of which is invariant for $A$. (The argument can be made rigorous using Zorn's lemma.) Then apply the separable result to each summand and sum up.

As for $A = U^{-1}[\tau]U$, that really is an immediate consequence of $(UAU^{-1}f)(m) = \tau(m)f(m)$.

Comment: Hey Nik! Thanks for the answer! I think I got the idea! I've checked some references besides Reed & Simon but all of them omitted the proof by saying that "you can use Zorn Lemma to prove it" and I didn't even know where to begin. Now it's pretty much clearer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW: what should I do with the post on mathoverflow? Should I delet it? Don't know what is the best practice now hehe.

Comment: Yeah, I'd go ahead and delete the one on mathoverflow.  (I don't object to your posting it there after not getting an answer here, but you probably should have waited a little longer ...)

Comment: Yes! You are probably right. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose first that $\mathcal{H}$ is separable.  Then R&S's version directly implies Dimock's.  Note that the right side of (1) is precisely $([\tau] f)(m)$, so (1) can be written as $U A U^{-1} f = [\tau] f$ for all $f \in \mathcal{H}$, which is to say $U A U^{-1} = [\tau]$ as operators.  Now just multiply by $U^{-1}$ on the left and $U$ on the right to obtain the desired $A = U^{-1} [\tau] U$.  Thus we have exactly Dimock's conclusion, plus a little bit more: the conclusion is that $\mu$ is not only a measure but in particular a *finite* measure.

For the non-separable case, we have the following lemma: given a self-adjoint operator $A$ on $\mathcal{H}$, there is an orthogonal decomposition $\mathcal{H} = \bigoplus_{i \in I} \mathcal{H}_i$, for some index set $I$, where each $\mathcal{H}_i$ is separable and invariant under $A$.  The proof is an exercise in transfinite induction or Zorn's lemma.  The key idea is that if $\mathcal{H}_0$ is invariant under $A$, then by self-adjointness, $\mathcal{H}_0^\perp$ is also invariant under $A$.  So if $\mathcal{H}_0^\perp$ is nonzero, then pick any $x \in \mathcal{H}_0^{\perp}$ and consider $\mathcal{H}_1$, the closed linear span of $\{x, Ax, A^2 x, \dots\}$, which by construction is separable, orthogonal to $\mathcal{H}_0$, and invariant under $A$.  Replace $\mathcal{H}_0$ by $\mathcal{H}_0 \oplus \mathcal{H}_1$ and the induction continues.

Applying the separable case, there are measure spaces $(\mathcal{M}_i, \mu_i)$ and functions $\tau_i$ such that the restriction of $A$ to $\mathcal{H}_i$ is unitarily equivalent to $[\tau_i]$.  Set $\mathcal{M}$ to be the disjoint union of all the $\mathcal{M}_i$, with $\mu, \tau$ given by pasting together the $\mu_i, \tau_i$ in the obvious way, and it follows that $A$ is unitarily equivalent to $[\tau]$.

Comment: Amazing answer! Thanks so much!!